# How to remove a systemd wrapper script for sysV service and use a unit file instead?

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, arm

I'm trying to un-configure or remove a `systemd` wrapper script for an old sysV service. The wrapper is provided by a Debian package so I can't just delete it.

The wrapper shows up as an artifact and is listed as *"generated"*:

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i -E 'rng|rand'
rng-tools.service                      generated
systemd-random-seed.service            static
urandom.service                        static
```

I added a new `systemd` service to replace it according to [Creating and Modifying systemd Unit Files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files):

```
# touch /etc/systemd/system/rng-tools.service
# chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/rng-tools.service
# emacs /etc/systemd/system/rng-tools.service
<edit file>
```

However, when I try to enable the new service file the old sysV script is used instead:

```
# systemctl enable rng-tools
Synchronizing state of rng-tools.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable rng-tools
```

Searching has turned up 0 hits to remove the old wrapper. I get lots of similar hits, like creating a wrapper script. But I have not found information on removing one from `systemd`'s database.

How do I un-configure or remove a systemd wrapper script for sysV service?

---

And here are the result after Stephen's suggestion. The new `rng-tools.service` is being used:

```
$ systemctl status rng-tools
● rng-tools.service - Entropy daemon for /dev/random using a hardware RNG
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rng-tools.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-10-15 07:19:32 EDT; 20min a
 Main PID: 674 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

And:

```
# journalctl -b -u rng-tools.service
-- Logs begin at Mon 2018-10-15 07:19:29 EDT, end at Mon 2018-10-15 07:49:13 EDT. --
Oct 15 07:19:31 beaglebone systemd[1]: Started Entropy daemon for /dev/random using a hardware RNG.
Oct 15 07:19:31 beaglebone rngd[674]: can't open /dev/hwrng: No such file or directory
Oct 15 07:19:32 beaglebone systemd[1]: rng-tools.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 15 07:19:32 beaglebone systemd[1]: rng-tools.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 15 07:19:32 beaglebone systemd[1]: rng-tools.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And:

```
# dd if=/dev/hwrng count=16 bs=1
▒▒▒▒ȿ▒3▒▒ ▒▒#16+0 records in
16+0 records out
16 bytes (16 B) copied, 0.00942799 s, 1.7 kB/s
```

---

And for completeness, here is the new `rng-tools.service`:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/rng-tools.service
# ...

[Unit]
Description=Entropy daemon for /dev/random using a hardware RNG
After=syslog.target
Requires=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rngd -r /dev/hwrng -f

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

Comment: This is a follow-on question from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475489/ .

Answer (score 7):

```
Synchronizing state of rng-tools.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable rng-tools
```

only means that systemd is “aware” that there’s a `sysvinit`-style init script present, and that it needs to take it into account when considering the state of the `rng-tools` service. It doesn’t mean that it’s going to *use* the init script to manage the service.

If both an init script and a unit file are present, systemd will use the latter (at least, when the service isn’t running).

You can see which file is used to start a service by running `systemctl status`; the “Loaded” line will show which script was used. For example, here’s a service which has both  a systemd unit and an init script:

```
● infnoise.service - Wayward Geek InfNoise TRNG driver
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/infnoise.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
```

Here’s a service which only has an init script:

```
● sensord.service - LSB: lm-sensors daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/sensord; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
```

Checking your service *should* show that systemd is using your new unit.

If all else fails, you *can* delete `/etc/init.d/rng-tools`: it should be tracked as a conffile, and `dpkg` will note that it was deleted and won’t restore it on package upgrades. `/etc` is owned by the system administrator, not the packaging system, even though packages can install files there.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen. OK, so I removed the changes to `rc.local` that manually enabled `rng-tools`, and I left the new `rng-tools.service` in place. Unfortunately no joy. The service did not start and `/dev/random` is out of entropy. But it does look like the new service was used. It is amazing `/usr/sbin/rngd -r /dev/hwrng -f` works from `rc.local` but not `rng-tools.service`.

Comment: What does `systemctl status` show after trying to start the service? Could it be that `/dev/hwrng` isn’t available early enough?

Comment: Given the timestamps in the logs, I take it the unit fails to start at boot, is that right? What happens if you restart it afterwards? You might need to trigger the unit from a `udev` rule so that it starts after the `hwnrg` device is available.

Comment: M. Kitt may also be interested in the status of `dev-hwrng.device`.

Comment: @JdeBP that’s assuming that the `udev` rule tags the device appropriately; but we’re addressing [the parent question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/475489/86440) at this point...

Comment: @JdeBP - Forgive my ignorance... Should I add `After=dev-hwrng.device` (and `Requires`) in the new service file? (I'm in the [`systemd.unit` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) now looking for something similar).

Comment: OK, so adding `After=dev-hwrng.device` does not work as expected. It results in *`Dependency failed for...`*. `systemd` simply blows. No wonder Debian is not using it. God bless you guys for putting up with its crap. You should become Unix saints when you die.

Comment: `dev-hwnrg.device` will only exist (virtually) if the device is tagged, *i.e.* there’s a `udev` rule somewhere which reacts to the device’s creation and says `TAG+="systemd"`. If you provide that, then you’ll be able to make the `rng-tools` unit require `dev-hwrng.device`. (Unfortunately that’s not a generic, package-appropriate solution since it’s device specific...) See `man systemd.device` for details.

Comment: @Stephen - OK, so I tried to add a restart every 2 seconds until the service started as discussed at [Adding delay between stop and start of a process in systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/260973/56041). Now I can't SSH into the box. Man, I hate this f--king tool. It is nothing but misery. I don't blame Debian one bit for avoiding it. Thanks again for your help.